# Approximating on a line

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, interpolation, monotone-functions

Say I have sampled some points in $[0,1]^2$ and evaluate a function $f(x,y)$ for them. I am interested in the behavior of $f$ along a single dimension.

If the points were like $(x_1,y_1),(x_1,y_2),\ldots,(x_1,y_N)$, then they lie nicely on a straight line, such that I can compare $f(x_1,y_1),f(x_1,y_2),\ldots,f(x_1,y_N)$ to inspect the behavior along the $y$-dimension, since $x$ is fixed.

However, my points lie scattered, e.g. the red points in the figure. Is there a way to 'project' these points onto a straight line (the same fixed $x$-coordinate)?

In the figure the red points are the only points were I know $f(x,y)$. To inspect $f$ along the $y$-dimension, I want to inspect points along a fixed $x$-coordinate, in this case the black dashed line. Is there a way to 'project' the red points onto this black line, such that they become the black points?

[image]

I am familiar with interpolation methods, but I was wondering if there is a more mathematically motivated/exact method to do this. For example 'filter out' the $x$-contributions.

So far I have tried interpolating, but the results really depend on the method of interpolation. Furthermore I thought about weighting the contribution of each point, according to the distance between that point and the black line, but that hasn't been very fruitful either.

Any help/thoughts/ideas is very much appreciated :)

Comment: To project the red points to the black points, wouldn't you just set the $x$ of each point to $0.4$?

Comment: You need to formulate hypotheses on the behaviour of $f$. For a general function nothing can be said.

Comment: @cr001, the problem is that I only know $f$ for the red points and cannot evaluate it exactly for the black points.

Comment: Basically I am after $f(x+\Delta x,y)$, when I know $f(x,y)$

Comment: interpolation is very mathematical method. dependency on the interpolation method...say little unclear to me what do you mean. can you add some more information about interpolations you tried and this dependency

Comment: Do you have *any* information about what $f$ really is? Are you just given the numbers or are they measurements (and is that case; of what)? I second what Justpassingby said: you need to have a model for $f$ otherwise you can't say anything. There is no magical method that works in general; but there are many things that could work in specific cases.

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky and Winther. $f$ will be of the form $f(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ and represents an option value depending on $d$ risk drivers. What I know of $f$, is that it is non-negative, what I want to know is along which dimensions (i.e. along which risk drivers) it is monotone.

Comment: should it be taken as an axiom that  $f$ is monotonic function in either $x$ or $y$ we just don't know which one or it is more general?

Comment: I see in the question I did not mention monotonicity. It should not be assumed $f$ is monotonic in either $x$ or $y$. The reason that I want to approximate along a line, is that I then have information about $f$ along a _single_ dimension, such that I can test the monotonicity of $f$ along that line (i.e. along that dimension).

Comment: why not to investigate partial derivatives? Numerically you take differences of subsequent entries in rows (dx) or in columns (dy). Then you look at change of sign.

Comment: Yes I understand, but that is the next step. Once I have these approximated function values on a line I can evaluate them for monotonicity, e.g. using what you just said. But my question is about how to approximate the function on that line most accurately.

Comment: The first thing you need for the monitonicity is to investigate the sign of derivative. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/168325

If you want it along the other line then a parallel to some axis then it would be a directional derivative (you obtain it from dx dy as well).

Comment: in case of noisy data read (I don't have access though) http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025512008018

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky, as I said, my question is not about monotonicity. I know how to test for monotonicity. But testing for monotonicity needs to be done in 1 dimension, that is what my question is about: translating more-dimensional data to a 1-dimensional line.

Comment: Even if the data collected at not uniformly distributed points (even scattered) and your function is monotonic say in $x$ the differences $u_{i}^j-u_{i+1}^j$ will  all have the same signs. Note that usually approximation of the data will not necessarily preserve monotonicity unless it was known and taken in account by the approximation method. The only approximation that automatically preserve the monotonicity is piece-wise linear interpolation.

Comment: How is that? Consider you've sampled for points in the $(x,y)$ region: $A=(0,0)$, $B=(2,0)$ and $C=(2,1)$. Then $f(x,y)=y-x$ evaluated at these points gives $f(A)=0$, $f(B)=-2$ and $f(C)=-1$. Now to inspect monotonicity along the $y$-direction, according to you one could **1.** inspect $f(A)$ and $f(C)$, concluding decreasingness, or **2.** inspect $f(B)$ and $f(C)$, concluding increasingness....

Comment: $f(A) -f(C)$  is not what I suggest to do, but if you assume $f$ continuous then is $c\in[0,1]$ such that $f(B)-f(C)\approx \alpha f_y(2,c)$. Similarly $fA)-f(B)\approx \beta f_x(d,0)$ for $d\in[0,2])$. Of course the more points you have the better the test you perform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a table $(x_i,y_i,f(x_i,y_i))_{i=1}^n$. And a fixed value of $x$, denoted below as $x^*$.

If the $y_i$'s are unique you don't have an interpolation,
but a Taylor expansion or so, which is an extrapolation. If they are not unique and you have values around given\fixed $x^*$, i.e. from both sides, then you can have uni-variable interpolation for this value. However, this won't use information from different values of $y_i$ which may affect the quality of your comparison along $y$ dimention, i.e.  $f(x^*,y_j)$.

You can try any of the following:

1. Define $w_i = \frac{1}{\|(x^*,y_i)\|_2^q} $ for some $q>0$

   Then $$f(x^*,y) \approx \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i,v_i) v_i$$ where $$v_i =
   w_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^n w_j \right)^{-1}$$

   This would be Shepard's Method, some modifications are available,
   [see](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~bonzo/docs/MyThesis.pdf).
2. The approach above can be generalized as a approximation by a
   [radial basis functions](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0307904X02001014), or its modifications, e.g. [this
   link](http://www.unizar.es/galdeano/actas_pau/PDFIX/BozLen05.pdf). Note also this [link](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7561/do-rbf-kernel-matrices-tend-to-be-ill-conditioned). You can find matlab implementation of such approach
   [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10056-scattered-data-interpolation-and-approximation-using-radial-base-functions).
3. You can also consider [splines](http://csweb.engr.ccny.cuny.edu/~wolberg/pub/tvcg97.pdf) if you like.
4. The [Least Squares Fit](http://www.nealen.net/projects/mls/asapmls.pdf) is also good option.

---

Now about choosing the best $x^*$

Note the quality of the approximation is vary for a different $x^*$ and for different methods the better result is obtained at different $x^*$.

A naive method would be to choose something between all known $x_i$'s, e.g.
$$x^*=\mathop{\mathrm{argmin}}\limits_{x^*\in[x_1,x_n]} \|x^*-x\|,$$ where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ are known values from the table.

However what you really want is $x^*$ that minimize
$$Error(x^*)=\|f(x,y)-\tilde f(x^*,y)\|$$
where $f(x,y) = (f(x_1,y_1),\dots,f(x_n,y_n))$ and $\tilde f$ is the approximant. Generally to speak, you need
to know to approximate the error term of the method you use at given point.

---

I'm adding another possible definition of error measurement (based on Shepard-like methods) suggested by `A.S.` in comments. Whether they are equivalent or one should be preferred on another is a question atm. However, I guess it can be used as well.
$$Error(f,\tilde f)=E\left(\sum_i \frac{||f(x_i,y_i)-f(x^*,Y)||}{||(x_i,y_i)-(x^*,Y)||}\right)$$

Comment: What exactly is $x^*$ that needs estimation? Aren't we just trying to evaluate function at $(x,y)$ for some fixed/given $x$?

Comment: This is the fixed $x$, the one for which the comparison along $y$ direction will work the best due to better approximation. As I see it, OP doesn't compare for all $x$'s, otherwise this part is redundant.

Comment: In $Error(x^*)$ you compare function/approximation evaluated at different points. Could you explain reasoning behind that?

Comment: There is no comparison, but a definition of error. I suggest to find $x^*$ that minimizes this error to make the investigation of the function along $y$-dimension more reliable.

Comment: $f(x,y)-f(x^*,y)$ is comparison of the two terms you are subtracting. I was asking about the reasoning behind this particular choice of error as to me it doesn't seem natural/popping out.

Comment: Note the tilde $f(x,y)-\tilde f(x^*,y)$ , one is the real $f$ (which is unknown) the other is approximant. This is just a definition of error of approximation. I put it in norm and the norm isn't specified, i.e. it is pretty much general definition. I choose this form because of it generality. So what's wrong?

Comment: You are evaluating $f$ at $(x_i,y_i)$ and $\tilde f$ at $(x^*,y_i)$ (that is different points) so this is not a "general definition". I don't think anything is wrong per se, but you are making a choice to compare $f(p_i)$ with $f(p^*_i)$ where $p^*_i$ is projection of $p_i$ onto the line $x=x^*$. While the simplest, that's certainly not the only choice and it seems rather unrobust to my (untrained in these matters) eye. This is separate from picking a norm for the distance.

Comment: I think this is what OP asking for. But if you have another choice please state it.

Comment: I read it as OP interested  in $f(x^*,y)$ for *all* $y$, not just for $y=y_i$. Even if we only consider points with $y=y_i$ and we go along with your general idea to use single point approximations, if $x_i-x^*$ is large, you certainly should underweight $f(x_i,y_i)-f(x^*,y_i)$ compared to others, so you can't just take the norm you chose.

Comment: My suggestion, based on $(1)$ would be $Error(f,\tilde f)=E\left(\sum_i \frac{||f(x_i,y_i)-f(x^*,Y)||}{||(x_i,y_i)-(x^*,Y)||}\right)$ where you can choose distribtuion of $Y$ based on which points you want to approximate better (discrete measure the way you understood OP).

Comment: I see what you say. In general, considering interpolation - usually you use several close points to the point of interest rather then all points because this provide a smaller error. So, I'm not sure you right, but I have to think about this more.

Comment: If you make the norm in the denominator of the error term suggested rapidly increasing in terms of euclidean distance (say exponential), then it would pick up only points that are closest to $(x*,Y)$ - so that flexibility is already build-in.

Comment: the important question is, would it work numerically?

Comment: another question is, since your suggestion based on (1) - you generally asking a weighted norm (which doesn't contradict my definition yet). The main difference is that you ask to test it across all points of $y$, which I'm not yet sure is necessarily give better result, but probably can be used. Although, perhaps this can also be expressed as a norm. I don't try to say your suggestion is bad or wrong, I just not yet sure I would use it.

Comment: I don't know since, as I mentioned, this isn't my area of expertise. But comparing $f(x^*,y_i)$ to $f(x_i,y_i)$ only certainly doesn't make for a meaningful error definition unless we make some wild assumptions about $f$. But my suggestion is completely in line with what you offered in 1 - so if we choose that method, we should consider choosing this error form - in the least for consistency. As I said, choosing a discrete measure on for $Y$ would also test only across $y_i$. The main difference is weighting by $d^{-1}((x_i,y_i),(x^*,y_i))$ - not different measures on $Y$ and this is essential

Comment: I've added your option and referred you.

Comment: you welcome to edit this part if you want to add something.

Comment: @A.S. and Michael, thank you both for you efforts. I agree with A.S. that comparing $f$ and its approximation in different point does not seem robust. Note that I want to interpolate, so $x^*$ should be chosen such that the points that discretize the black line (let's call them $(x^*,y^*_1),\ldots,(x^*,y^*_m)$) lie "well" with regard to the data points $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_N,y_N)$. More specifically, I want to choose $x^*$, such that the approximation based on $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_N,y_N)$ in the points $(x^*,y^*_1),\ldots,(x^*,y^*_m)$ will be most accurate. I know this depends on the ...

Comment: _(continued)_... method of interpolation, but my first guesses for $x^*$ were the average or the median of the $x_1,\ldots,x_N$, such that $x^*$ lies nicely "centered" between the $x_1,\ldots,x_N$.

Comment: if $x-y$ is proportional to $f(x)-f(y)$ then you can do it, otherwise it may be not the best choice. Still if it works for you needs (i.e. the accuracy is not worsen then needed) you can use it.

Comment: what do you mean with _it_?

Comment: not sure what was not clear - please ask more specific question.

Comment: You said: if $x-y$ is proportional to $f(x)-f(y)$ then you can do **it**, otherwaise **it** may not be the best choice. Still if **it** works for your needs (i.e. the accuracy is not worse than needed) you can use **it**. What do you mean with **it**?

Comment: I mean taking the median of $x$'s. 
For example $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, if you take $x_1=0.1$ and  $x_2=0.3$ and  fix $x=0.2$ then you get $|f(0.1)-f(0.2)|=5$ but $|f(0.3)-f(0.2)|=\frac{5}{3}= 1.6(6)$. However if you choose $x=0.15=1.3(3)$ then   $|f(0.1)-f(0.15)|=\frac{10}{3}=|f(0.3)-f(0.15)|$ which $x$ will best serve your needs?

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. Note that I want to interpolate at $x^*$, such that the distance between the location of my data **points** is most important, not distance between the _function values_ at those data points. In that sense I want $x^*$ such that the points where I interpolate lie at the 'center' of my data points. To return to your example, I think $x=0.2$ would be a better choice than $x=0.15$, since $x=0.2$ lies exactly in the center of the data points $x_1=0.1$ and $x_2=0.3$.

Comment: as I said, if the accuracy is not the issue, then ok.